# Can I keep WebRTC audio or video from WKWebView playing when app is backgrounded?

Tags: ios, webrtc, wkwebview

An iOS app shows a WKWebView streaming video and audio via WebRTC.

If I press the home button to background the app (on iOS 16.5.1), the audio stops.

Is it possible for the audio to keep playing in the background? Or even the video via picture-in-picture?